# Django Test Runner can't find tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, test-runner

I am running into issues with the Django (1.10.6) Test Runner being unable to find my tests. I am using Python 3.6.

The following works:

`python manage.py test apps.foo`

but this does not:

`python manage.py test`

My project structure looks as follows:

```
apps/
  foo/
    migrations/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
manage.py
```

And `tests.py` looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase


class ConfirmationTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_email_confirm(self):
        pass
```

In my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  ...
  'apps.foo',
)
```

Is there any reason why the Test Runner would fail to pick up my tests?

Comment: have you added 'apps' in your INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question in include my INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the issue. As suspected it was something dumb.

I was missing a `__init__.py` in my `apps` directory.

```
apps/
  foo/
    migrations/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
  __init__.py <-- the offender
manage.py
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple other places to look:

- Test filenames should start with `test`
- The methods within the tests should start with `test`
- If you're using a `tests` directory be sure to add `__init__.py` to the those test folders

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: I was having the same symptom because there was an *extra* `__init__.py` file in the project's directory (the same directory that contains manage.py)

Applications to test were found but then I'd get an error that . could not be imported.